# Mathematical proof pattern

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, solution-verification

Consider the following proof pattern. We prove a statement S in four steps:

1. Find two suitable mathematical statements T and U .
2. Prove T , assuming S is false.
3. Prove U , assuming S is false.
4. Prove that not both T and U are true.

We want to use propositional logic to reason about the soundness of this proof pattern.

How could I form this proof pattern into logic expressions F and G and prove that F $\models$ G holds or does not hold?

Comment: Is the statement S already proved to be false, or do you have other method to prove its falsity?

Comment: we want to show that S is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I dont use the full scope of symbols, the scheme of logical reasoning is as follows:
We have, by your proposition:
If $\sim S\implies \text{U&T}$. Now you prove the falsity of $\text{U&T}$. This in turn proves the veracity of $S$, because, we have $\sim \text{U&T}\implies\sim(\sim S)=S$. Note that it is sufficient if we only prove one implication and the falsity of the implied statement.

Comment: I think you mean not $S$ implies $U\&T$, right?

Comment: @NoahSolomon yes, edited